# Compare existing tableview row number to new tableview row number

Tags: uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, catransition

I am trying to implement  pageCurl or pageUnCurl functionality into a splitviewcontroller app. Basically I need to keep track of which row in a tableView is popping a new view so that it will curl or uncurl the page depending on its relative position.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
     */
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSUInteger pagenumber=1;
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *whatdetailViewController = nil;


    if (row == 0) {

        DetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
        whatdetailViewController = newDetailViewController;

            case 0: pagenumber++;

            case 1: pagenumber--;

        NSLog(@"pagenumber %i",pagenumber);
        NSLog(@"row %i",row);
        if (pagenumber<row){
            [self pageUnCurl]; 
        }else{
            [self pageCurl];  
        }
    }

    if (row == 1) {

        SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        whatdetailViewController = newDetailViewController;


            case 0: pagenumber++;

            case 1: pagenumber--;

        NSLog(@"2pagenumber %i",pagenumber);
        NSLog(@"2row %i",row);
        if (pagenumber<row){
            [self pageUnCurl]; 
        }else{
            [self pageCurl];  
        }

     }
```

Is there an easy way to count up or down depending on the row selection?
Thank you

Update-
This works

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
     */
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *whatdetailViewController = nil;


    if (row == 0) {{

        DetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
        whatdetailViewController = newDetailViewController;
        if (exitRow>row){
        [self pageUnCurl];  
        } else {
            [self pageCurl];
            }

        }
        exitRow=row;
    }
    if (row == 1) {{

        SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        whatdetailViewController = newDetailViewController;
        if (exitRow>row){
            [self pageUnCurl];  
        } else {
            [self pageCurl];
            }

        }
        exitRow=row;

    }
}
```